# To find order of centre of G

Tags: group-theory

Let G be group of order8 generated by a and b such that $a^{4} = b^{2} =1$ and $ ba = a^{3} b $ , then how to found order of centre of G

Comment: If all else fails there are only $16$ possible elements $a^rb^r$. Write out the (finite) multiplication table to work out which of the possibilities are equal to each other, and which commute with everything. You might notice something about the parity of the exponents.

Comment: @Mark's suggestion can be carried out a little faster by noting that it is enough for an element to commute with each of the generators. But why do you say $G$ has order 8 only? As far as I can see all the 16 combinations should be distinct -- is there an additional relation you forgot to quote?

Comment: @HenningMakholm no nothing

Comment: @HenningMakholm I assumed $8$ because it was in the question and didn't check.

Comment: Are you sure  the first relation isn't $ a^4=b^2=1 $?

Comment: @Bernard oh yes , m mistake

Comment: @MarkBennet can you please elaborate

Comment: @Sophie, then perhaps you recognize $G$ as the dihedral group of order 8 with its the standard presentation?

Comment: @HenningMakholm but order?

Comment: @SophieClad: Just start by finding the center explicitly, listing all its elements. Then count them.

Comment: I am not familiar with dihedral group .is there any otherway

Answer (score 1):

$$Z(G)=\{g\in G: gx=xg ,\forall x\in G\}.$$
Now, $ba=a^3b$ and hence $a,b,a^3$ are not central.
Also,
$$bab^{-1}=a^3 \Rightarrow (bab^{-1})^2=ba^2b^{-1}=a^2,$$
and hence $a^2$ commute with $b$.
Clearly, $a^2$ commute with all powers of $a$ and hence $a^2$ is central.

From here it is easy to check that 
$$Z(G)= \langle a^2 \rangle =\{1,a^2\}.$$